# Determine if dom element contains a highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my web app, I am trying to implement different behaviors for click and mouseup events for text elements. On a mouseup event, I check if there is a selected text and do something with it. On a click event I do something else, like navigating somewhere regarding clicked text. If there is a selected text, however, I won't execute the code on click event and this is the part I got stuck. Here is a modal of what I am doing now:

```js
//the function that returns selected text as string
function getSelectionText() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return text;
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
  var selection = getSelectionText();
  if (selection != "") {
    alert("Selected text: " + selection);
  }

}

function onClick(event) {
  alert("You clicked the text.");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2 onclick="onClick(); return false;" onmouseup="onMouseUp(); return false;">
    text to click or select
  </h2>
</body>
```

I want to do something like this in the onClick handler

```
function onClick(event)
{
  if ( !hasSelectedParts(this) ) // want to implement hasSelectedParts() function
  {
      alert("You clicked the text.");
  }
}
```

How can I implement that hasSelectedParts(domElement) function? That is,
is there a simple way of detecting whether a dom element has some selected parts in it.

Comment: `window.getSelection().anchorNode` ? might need to crawl around/up still, but that's the entry

Comment: Seconding @dandavis -- check out some documentation about [window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for any help in comments. Here is what I came up with:

```
function hasSelectedContend(element)
{
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    return !selection.isCollapsed // selection data is about currently highlighted text
        && selection.anchorNode !== null // there is a selection
        && selection.anchorNode.parentNode === element; //selection is in the element
}
```